# How to generate description for image using Chat GPT API using "gpt-4-vision-preview" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

Here's with this code i want to generate description for the provided image with the help of Chat GPT API using "gpt-4-vision-preview" model. But the cide is not working. Please help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ImageDescController extends Controller
{
    
    public function describeImageWithText(Request $request)
    {
        $api_key = "**********************";

        $image_path = 'my_image_path';
        
        $base64_image = base64_encode($image_path);

        $client = new Client([
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$api_key}"
            ]
        ]);

        $payload = [
            'model' => 'gpt-4-vision-preview',
            'messages' => [
                [
                    'role' => 'user',
                    'content' => [
                        [
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'text' => "What is in the image?"
                        ],
                        [
                            'type' => 'image_url',
                            'image_url' => [
                                'url' => "data:image/jpeg;base64,{$base64_image}"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'max_tokens' => 300
        ];

        $response = $client->post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', [
            'json' => $payload
        ]);

        dd($response);

        return response()->json(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
        
    }


}
```

Tried uploading an image and want description as an output. Please provide a better solution. Also want to know if it is possible or not?

Comment: What is your error, where are you stuck?

Comment: Issue resolved. Just provided the image URL in the 'url', instead of encoded text.